# The type javax.servlet.ServletContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

This is in a Getting the error in this file on the package line. This is in a jhipster generated project

```
   package com.mycompany;

import com.fidelity.config.DefaultProfileUtil;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;


 public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    /**
     * set a default to use when no profile is configured.
     */
    DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(application.application());
    return application.sources(ModelMgmtApp.class);
}
```

}

Comment: which command is giving you that error?